# mp.release crashing soundboard app

Tags: android, audio, media-player

I am using the following code to play a sound and after a while it will stop playing sounds, this is because of too many instances of mediaplayer open I believe so I added an extra `mp.release();` and it just crashes my app (it's currently commented out).

Here is the actual code I am using.

```
public void audioPlayer(String path, String fileName){
    //set up MediaPlayer    
    MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
    if (mp!=null){
 //       mp.release();

       }

    try {
        mp.setDataSource(path+"/"+fileName);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        mp.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mp.start();

}
```

and to call it in my app I use:

```
audioPlayer(sdcard + "/soundboard","s1sound1.ogg");
```

can anyone tell me why it's crashing and what do I need to do to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#Valid_and_Invalid_States),

> after release the object is no longer
>   available

So you can't perform any action on it. if you create a new `MediaPlayer` object, there's no need to call release on it anyway.

Instead, you can do:

```
public void audioPlayer(String path, String fileName){
    if (mp != null)
        mp.release();    
    mp = new MediaPlayer();
    ....
```

And declare `MediaPlayer mp;` as a class member, not local.

Comment: This works, or personally I'd just use `mp.reset();`. Also, MrCloister, try putting your set, prepare, and start methods into a single try/catch instead of separating them like that.

Comment: Hey guys, Thanks for your help.

I am still having a problem with the audio only playing a certain amount of times, any ideas whats wrong?  I'll post my current code in the initial post under EDIT

Comment: wait I'm talking out of my bottom Thank you it works just fine